# Update on: How to model random non-overlapping spheres of non-uniform size in a cube using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random, geometry

I am trying to use MATLAB for generating random locations for non-uniform size spheres (non-overlapping) in a cube. The for loop in the code below never seems to end. I don't know what am missing in the code. I have ran the code for no. of spheres (n) = 10; dims = [ 10 10 10 ]

```
    function [ c r ] = randomSphere( dims )
    % creating one sphere at random inside [0..dims(1)]x[0..dims(2)]x...
    % radius and center coordinates are sampled from a uniform distribution 
    % over the relevant domain.
    % output: c - center of sphere (vector cx, cy,... )
    %         r - radius of sphere (scalar)
    r = rand(1); % you might want to scale this w.r.t dims or other consideration
    c = r + rand( size(dims) )./( dims - 2*r ); % make sure sphere does not exceed boundaries

   function ovlp = nonOverlapping( centers, rads )
   % check if several spheres with centers and rads overlap or not
   ovlp = false;
   if numel( rads ) == 1
   return; % nothing to check for a single sphere
   end
   dst = sqrt( sum( bsxfun( @minus, permute( centers, [1 3 2] ),...
                             permute( centers, [3 1 2] ) ).^2, 3) );
   ovlp = dst >= bsxfun( @plus, rads, rads.' ); %' all distances must be smaller than r1+r2
   ovlp = any( ovlp(:) ); % all must not overlap


   function [centers rads] = sampleSpheres( dims, n )
   % dims is assumed to be a row vector of size 1-by-ndim

   % preallocate
   ndim = numel(dims);
   centers = zeros( n, ndim );
   rads = zeros( n, 1 );
   ii = 1;
   while ii <= n
   [centers(ii,:), rads(ii) ] = randomSphere( dims );     
   if nonOverlapping( centers(1:ii,:), rads(1:ii) )
     ii = ii + 1; % accept and move on
   end
end
```

Comment: Just a hint: it is not recommended to use matlab function names as variable names. In this case you overwrite the length()-function, which could cause some unforseen consequences later, should you try to use the length()-function.

Answer (score 1):

Without writing a single line of code, i would propose the following idea:
Discretize your 3d-space in a fine grid (using meshgrid). Instead of using rand() for your coordinates, you will now randomly pick one valid tuple of those pre-defined coordinates for your spheres. Therefore you first choose your radius of the current sphere, then filter from all possible coordinates the valid ones, i.e. where the sphere with it's given radius would not intersect with either the boundaries or another sphere.

Best, Nras.

Comment: Hey Nras,
That's something i would give a try, if i don't get the below code work.

Answer (score 0):

You can iteratively add new random spheres, check if they are valid (not intersecting other spheres, not exceeding boundaries, etc.), and accept valid random spheres until you have enough of them.

```
function [ c r ] = randomSphere( dims )
% creating one sphere at random inside [0..dims(1)]x[0..dims(2)]x...
% radius and center coordinates are sampled from a uniform distribution 
% over the relevant domain.
%
% output: c - center of sphere (vector cx, cy,... )
%         r - radius of sphere (scalar)
r = rand(1); % you might want to scale this w.r.t dims or other consideration
c = r + rand( size(dims) )./( dims - 2*r ); % make sure sphere does not exceed boundaries
```

Now that we know how to generate a single random sphere we would like to know how to check if several spheres overlap

```
function ovlp = nonOverlapping( centers, rads )
% check if several spheres with centers and rads overlap or not
ovlp = false;
if numel( rads ) == 1
   return; % nothing to check for a single sphere
end
dst = sqrt( sum( bsxfun( @minus, permute( centers, [1 3 2] ),...
                                 permute( centers, [3 1 2] ) ).^2, 3 );
ovlp = dst >= bsxfun( @plus, rads, rads.' ); %' all distances must be smaller than r1+r2
ovlp = any( ovlp(:) ); % all must not overlap
```

Finally, we can start generating several spheres sequentially, checking for overlap after every one:

```
function [centers rads] = sampleSpheres( dims, n )
% dims is assumed to be a row vector of size 1-by-ndim

% preallocate
ndim = numel(dims);
centers = zeros( n, ndim );
rads = zeros( n, 1 );
ii = 1;
while ii <= n
    [centers(ii,:), rads(ii) ] = randomSphere( dims );     
    if nonOverlapping( centers(1:ii,:), rads(1:ii) )
         ii = ii + 1; % accept and move on
    end
end
```

---

Note that this approach might land you in an infinite loop in case you ask for large `n` with small `dims` - you "fill" all the space with less that `n` spheres and then you are unable to generate new ones. Choose carefully `n` and `dims` and you might also want to have more control over the distribution of the sampled `r`.

Comment: Hey!Am getting infinite loop for any values of dims and n. I started of with dims = [ 3 3 3 ]; n = 2; just a basic case to see whether the code works ( but it just goes in an infinite loop). I am trying hard to improve the code but have found little success.
The final objective is to have around 200-300 random spheres.

Comment: Hey Shai!
Let me know how to change it. I got the basic idea behind the algorithm but still getting infinite loop for any values of dims and n.
@Nras, it would be great if you can have a look too.